# Gradle api configuration not working as expected

Tags: gradle

I am having trouble understanding the difference between the `api` and `implementation` configurations in Gradle. I know this has been asked before, but they seem to behave exactly oppositely of how everyone describes. I have three Gradle projects: consumer -> libraryA -> libraryB. libraryA has an `api` dependency on libraryB, and consumer has an `implementation` dependency on libraryA, however libraryB is not available on any classpath in consumer. When I change libraryA to have an `implementation` dependency on libraryB, libraryB becomes available on the runtimeClasspath of consumer. This does not seem to comport with what everyone is saying. What am I missing?

libraryB

```
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Kotlin library project to get you started.
 */

plugins {
    maven
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm").version("1.3.31")
}

group = "libraryB"

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // Use the Kotlin JDK 8 standard library.
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    // Use the Kotlin test library.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")

    // Use the Kotlin JUnit integration.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")
}
```

libraryA:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Kotlin library project to get you started.
 */

plugins {
    maven
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm").version("1.3.31")
}

group = "libraryA"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // if I change this to implementation, libraryB will be on the runtime classpath of consumer
    api("libraryB:libraryB:unspecified")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    // Use the Kotlin test library.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")

    // Use the Kotlin JUnit integration.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")
}
```

consumer:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Kotlin application project to get you started.
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the Kotlin JVM plugin to add support for Kotlin on the JVM.
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm").version("1.3.31")

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application.
    application
}

group = "com.consumer"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("libraryA:libraryA:unspecified")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    // Use the Kotlin test library.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")

    // Use the Kotlin JUnit integration.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application
    mainClassName = "com.consumer.AppKt"
}
```

In consumer: `gradle dependencies`

```
> Task :dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

-api (n)
No dependencies

-runtime (n)
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified (n)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31 (n)

annotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'main'.
No dependencies

api - API dependencies for compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

apiDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

apiElements - API elements for main. (n)
No dependencies

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compileClasspath - Compile classpath for compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)).
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
     |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31
          \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)

compileOnly - Compile only dependencies for compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

compileOnlyDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31
|         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
|         |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|         |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31
|              \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31 (*)

implementation - Implementation only dependencies for compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)). (n)
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified (n)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31 (n)

implementationDependenciesMetadata
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
     |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31
          \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)

kotlinCompilerClasspath
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
     |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.31
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
     \--- org.jetbrains.intellij.deps:trove4j:1.0.20181211

kotlinCompilerPluginClasspath
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable:1.3.31

kotlinNativeCompilerPluginClasspath
No dependencies

kotlinScriptDef - Script filename extensions discovery classpath configuration
No dependencies

kotlinScriptDefExtensions
No dependencies

runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)).
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31
|         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
|         |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|         |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31
|              \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31 (*)

runtimeElements - Elements of runtime for main. (n)
No dependencies

runtimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

runtimeOnlyDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

sourceArtifacts (n)
No dependencies

testAnnotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'test'.
No dependencies

testApi - API dependencies for compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

testApiDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

testCompileClasspath - Compile classpath for compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)).
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31
|         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.3.31
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common:1.3.31
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common:1.3.31
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.3.31 (*)
     \--- junit:junit:4.12
          \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

testCompileOnly - Compile only dependencies for compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

testCompileOnlyDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

testImplementation - Implementation only dependencies for compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)). (n)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.3.31 (n)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.3.31 (n)

testImplementationDependenciesMetadata
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31
|         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.3.31
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common:1.3.31
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common:1.3.31
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.3.31 (*)
     \--- junit:junit:4.12
          \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

testKotlinScriptDef - Script filename extensions discovery classpath configuration
No dependencies

testKotlinScriptDefExtensions
No dependencies

testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)).
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31
|         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
|         |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|         |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31
|              \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.3.31
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common:1.3.31
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common:1.3.31
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.3.31 (*)
     \--- junit:junit:4.12
          \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

testRuntimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

testRuntimeOnlyDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

(n) - Not resolved (configuration is not meant to be resolved)

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 604ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Now with libraryA having an `implementation` dependency on `libraryB`:

```
> Task :dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

-api (n)
No dependencies

-runtime (n)
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified (n)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31 (n)

annotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'main'.
No dependencies

api - API dependencies for compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

apiDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

apiElements - API elements for main. (n)
No dependencies

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compileClasspath - Compile classpath for compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)).
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
     |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31
          \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)

compileOnly - Compile only dependencies for compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

compileOnlyDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified
|    +--- libraryB:libraryB:unspecified
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31
|    |         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
|    |         |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|    |         |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31
|    |              \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31 (*)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31 (*)

implementation - Implementation only dependencies for compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)). (n)
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified (n)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31 (n)

implementationDependenciesMetadata
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
     |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31
          \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)

kotlinCompilerClasspath
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
     |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.31
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
     \--- org.jetbrains.intellij.deps:trove4j:1.0.20181211

kotlinCompilerPluginClasspath
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable:1.3.31

kotlinNativeCompilerPluginClasspath
No dependencies

kotlinScriptDef - Script filename extensions discovery classpath configuration
No dependencies

kotlinScriptDefExtensions
No dependencies

runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)).
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified
|    +--- libraryB:libraryB:unspecified
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31
|    |         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
|    |         |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|    |         |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31
|    |              \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31 (*)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31 (*)

runtimeElements - Elements of runtime for main. (n)
No dependencies

runtimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

runtimeOnlyDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

sourceArtifacts (n)
No dependencies

testAnnotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'test'.
No dependencies

testApi - API dependencies for compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

testApiDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

testCompileClasspath - Compile classpath for compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)).
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31
|         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.3.31
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common:1.3.31
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common:1.3.31
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.3.31 (*)
     \--- junit:junit:4.12
          \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

testCompileOnly - Compile only dependencies for compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

testCompileOnlyDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

testImplementation - Implementation only dependencies for compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)). (n)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.3.31 (n)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.3.31 (n)

testImplementationDependenciesMetadata
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31
|         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.3.31
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common:1.3.31
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common:1.3.31
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.3.31 (*)
     \--- junit:junit:4.12
          \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

testKotlinScriptDef - Script filename extensions discovery classpath configuration
No dependencies

testKotlinScriptDefExtensions
No dependencies

testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)).
+--- libraryA:libraryA:unspecified
|    +--- libraryB:libraryB:unspecified
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31
|    |         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31
|    |         |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|    |         |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31
|    |              \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.3.31
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common:1.3.31
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.31 (*)
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common:1.3.31
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.31
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.3.31 (*)
     \--- junit:junit:4.12
          \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

testRuntimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

testRuntimeOnlyDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

(n) - Not resolved (configuration is not meant to be resolved)

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 564ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

**Note** I am using version 6.2.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So my problem was that I wasn't enabling the `java-library` plugin. Once I added that to libraryA, libraryB successfully appeared on the compileClasspath of consumer.

So the correct build.gradle.kts for libraryA is:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Kotlin library project to get you started.
 */

plugins {
    maven
    `java-library`
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm").version("1.3.31")
}

group = "libraryA"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    api("libraryB:libraryB:unspecified")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    // Use the Kotlin test library.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")

    // Use the Kotlin JUnit integration.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")
}
```